# Unsupported Locale Filipino Philippines [fil_PH] in Coldfusion & Lucee

Tags: coldfusion, locale, cfml, lucee

Here, I'm working on Locale translation process for **Filipino (Philippines) - fil_PH** country.

```
<cfdump var="#getlocale()#" />
<cfset locale = setLocale("fil_PH")>
<cfdump var="#locale#" />
```

fil_PH is an country code for Filipino ( Philippines ). But seems both Coldfusion & Lucee not support the Fil_PH locale. And it's return "**unsupported Locale [fil_PH]**" issue.  Could any one have alternate way to achieve this ?

**Note :** ACF & Lucee support English (Philippines) - ( en-PH ) but I don't want that. I should use fil_PH locale only. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple issues here unfortunately.

1. Adobe Coldfusion only supports setting the locale to a locale which is supported by the JVM used by your installation.
2. `fil` is an ISO 639-2 language code, which means it is much less likely to be supported than any of the two character ISO 639-1 language codes, such as English `en` and Tagalog `tl`.

You can try out the following tests on https://trycf.com/gist/fc93fdc570909c1655e5f8a38dc25911/lucee5?theme=monokai

```
<cfdump var="#Server.ColdFusion.SupportedLocales#" label="Server.ColdFusion.SupportedLocales" />
<br />---
<cfdump var="#getlocale()#" />
<br />---
<cfset locale = setLocale("en_PH")>
<cfdump var="#getlocale()#" />

<br />---
<cftry>
    <cfset locale = setLocale("tl_PH")>
    <cfdump var="#getlocale()#" />
<cfcatch>
    <cfdump var="#cfcatch#" expand="false" label="#cfcatch.message#" />
</cfcatch>
</cftry>

<br />---
<cftry>
    <cfset variables.Locale=createObject('java','java.util.Locale') />
    <cfset setLocale(variables.Locale.init("tl","PH")) />
    <cfdump var="#getlocale()#" />
<cfcatch>
    <cfdump var="#cfcatch#" expand="false" label="#cfcatch.message#" />
</cfcatch>
</cftry>

<br />---
<cftry>
    <cfset locale = setLocale("fil_PH") />

    <cfdump var="#getlocale()#" />
<cfcatch>
    <cfdump var="#cfcatch#" expand="false" label="#cfcatch.message#" />
</cfcatch>
</cftry>

<br />---
<cftry>
    <cfset variables.Locale=createObject('java','java.util.Locale') />
    <cfset setLocale(variables.Locale.init("fil","PH")) />
    <cfdump var="#getlocale()#" />
<cfcatch>
    <cfdump var="#cfcatch#" expand="false" label="#cfcatch.message#" />
</cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Using `setLocale('xx_YY')`:

- Adobe Coldfusion supports `en_PH` but neither `tl_PH` nor `fil_PH`
- Lucee 5 supports `en_PH` and `tl_PH` but not `fil_PH`

Using Java you can try to create, initialise and set an otherwise unsupported locale:

```
<cfset variables.Locale=createObject('java','java.util.Locale') />
<cfset setLocale(variables.Locale.init("fil","PH")) />
```

- Adobe Coldfusion still errors with any unsupported locales using this method.
- Lucee 5 accepts setting `fil_PH` with this method - and on trycf.com, even recognises it as `Filipino (Philippines)` if you dump `getLocale()` after setting it.

So the easy answer is to use this workaround, however how well this workaround actually works in practice with other parts of the language and your application, I cannot predict, so use it at your own risk :-)

The 'proper' solution, would be to get the locale added to your JVM configuration - the method for that depends upon your Java version, skills, and level of server access. Or in the case of Lucee, you may be able to convince the Lucee team to add support to Lucee itself - they did it for this person https://luceeserver.atlassian.net/browse/LDEV-1876 who asked for `cy_GB` to be added for Welsh, so there is some precedent at least, however that was at least still an alpha-2 ISO 639-1 code. The Lucee devs may refuse `fil` on the basis of it being an ISO 639-2 alpha-3 code.

Comment: How do I rate this answer higher than a single upvote? Excellent write up. Any chance the just released ACF 2021 handles this?

Comment: Thanks. I don't have an Adobe CF2021 environment of my own yet, however on trycf.com theirs returned `The list of supported locales is stored in the variable Server.ColdFusion.SupportedLocales.` for both `fil_PH must be one of the ColdFusion supported locales.` and `tl_PH must be one of the ColdFusion supported locales.` - both with and without the createObject()+init() workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Sev Roberts already gave a very good answer. But I'm going to complement his answer with some more information. Setting locales with Codes as of ISO-639 and ISO-3166 `<cfset setLocale("xx_YY)>` won't always work. That is because from cfml history `setLocale()` function was first implemented to work with locale display names, and not their codes. They have been added later because of broader usage in the global world. However, using Lucee with an underlying Java version that has support of *java.util.Locale* for your locale  *"Filipino (Philippines)"*, Lucee should just work with `<cfset setLocale("Filipino (Philippines)")>`. Tested it with **AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.4** and **Lucee 6.0.0.13-SNAPSHOT**. This won't work on trycf.com, because they don't have a Java version that supports locale "Filipino (Philippines)". The code below runs on the above mentioned versions. It will also give you and others with similar locale issues some insights about the Java locale support of their running Lucee version. At the end it dumps the available Java locales.

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfset JavaLocale = CreateObject("java", "java.util.Locale")>
    <cfset availableJavaLocalesArray=JavaLocale.getAvailableLocales()>
    <cfloop array="#availableJavaLocalesArray#" index="index">
        <cfif index.getDisplayName() is "Filipino (Philippines)">
        Filipino Found
        <cfset setLocale(index.getDisplayName())>
        <div style="background: red;">#lscurrencyformat(1000.95)# #lsDateFormat(now())# #lsTimeFormat(now())#</div> 
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
<cfdump var="#availableJavaLocalesArray#">
```

See the output here:

[image]